# Possible Bug in "Looking for a job?" Box

Tags: bug, stack-overflow-jobs, advertising

I've been trying to dismiss some of the ads from "Looking for a job?" box; although after dismissal it says "Okay, you won't see this job anymore. Undo" I keep seeing them again (and again). Here are some screenshots before and after refreshing the page:

[image]
[image]
[image]

I think this is an issue just for nearby jobs that never get dismissed (my current location is Milan thus those near Milan). Don't know if it is a bug or a marketing strategy.

Comment: No, that's definitely a bug. I'll dig in and see what I can find here. Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: try { "Find a job" } catch { "JobNotFoundException" } :D

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Thanks for spotting this. Fix should be going up shortly.

#### TL;DR

As of a couple weeks ago, we stopped tracking who you were correctly when clicking on dismiss/undismiss.

---

#### Technical Details:

- To determine who you are, we use your Stack Exchange Network account id if you're logged in, and if not, then we use [a cookie](https://kevinmontrose.com/2015/01/27/providence-machine-learning-at-stack-exchange/).
- For job ads, we include a version number in our analytic data (so we can always go back and process old/historic analytic data when we need to).
- When dismissing / undismissing a job ad, there was some code that was looking at the version number of the analytic information sent along with the request to figure out how to access the account id, as it's different per version
- We updated the analytic version a few weeks ago, but the code that checks on that version number was overlooked (my bad!)
- This had the result of *always* using a cookie as the identifier for dismiss / undismiss requests. However, the code that filters out dismissed ads from being displayed was accessing the account id correctly, so the two systems were essentially disconnected.
- That code was old anyways, and has now been replaced with more robust code that doesn't need to do the version checking.

I hope that clears things up!

Comment: Note: I'm currently fixing another unrelated bug preventing a Prod deploy, but this fix will go out as soon as possible.

Comment: Wow that's like a lot of interesting stuff! It's crystal clear now! Thanks! :-)

Comment: Seeing what was causing the bug is sometimes more interesting than...really, just about anything.

Comment: @Draco18s Say bye to your weekend https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5bbug%5d%20is%3aa